# getTotal function not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert the following pseudo code into a javascript function (which calculates the price when checkboxes are selected by their title attribute):

```
function checkform(id) {
    CREATE a variable called total set as zero;
    GET a reference to the form into theForm;
    GET a reference to all the input elements in theForm into array aInputElements;

    FOR counter GOES FROM 1 TO aInputElements length
    STORE a reference to aInputElements[ counter ] into currentElement;
    IF currentElement is a checkbox AND currentElement is checked THEN
    total ← total + currentElement.value;
    ENDIF
    ENDFOR
}
```

So far i have this:

```
function getTotal() {

    // Get neccesary variables
    var total = 0,
        theForm = document.getElementById("bookingForm"),
        inputs = theForm.getElementsByTagName("input"),
        totalbox = document.getElementById("total");

    // Add event listener for when any checkbox changes
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

            var currentElement = inputs[i];

            if (currentElement.type == "checkbox") {
                total = total + currentElement.title;
        }

    }

    // Assign total to input
    totalbox.value = total;

}
```

However this isn't working and is adding:

"018.500.0013.0035.0016.0040.0015.0025.0016.0015.0027.5042.5020.0020.0020.000.000.0055.000.000.00" to the totalbox.value when any checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some flaws in your implementation.

1) To match your pseudocode, you need to verify that the checkbox is actually **checked**:

```
if (currentElement.type == "checkbox" && currentElement.checked)
```

2) The JavaScript `+` operator is not only used to add numbers, but also to concatenate strings. To avoid unexpected behavior, you will have to parse your input first (in this case the checkbox title containing the number). There is three solutions to do so:

```
// Explicit conversion into a number (as a float)
total = total + +currentElement.title;

// Parse into a number (as a float)
total = total + parseFloat(currentElement.title);

// Parse into a number (as an integer)
total = total + parseInt(currentElement.title);
```

3) Last advice in a more general domain, it would be better to use the [HTML5 Custom Data Attribute](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) to store data into a HTML element. In your case:

```
<!-- HTML code -->
<input type="checkbox" id="stackoverflow" data-total="12.34">

// JS code
var element = document.getElementById('stackoverflow');
var dataAsString = element.getAttribute('data-total');
var dataAsNumber = parseFloat(dataAsString);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it with this:

```
total = total + +currentElement.title;
```

Or simply:

```
total += +currentElement.title;
```

The extra `+` will force it to be read as a number and not a string.

---

- Obviously, you can use `parseFloat` instead as well on the title.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but now changes the totalbox.value to "378.5"

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing to float as below.

```
total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(currentElement.title);
```